# Swift: How to check a core data NSSet for an object

Tags: swift, contains, nsset

I am upgrading my code to Swift and am stuck on how to replicate my objective-c code to check for an existing record in a 1:many relationship, given one of the fields

```
    BOOL existingRecord = [[self.employeeRecord.absences valueForKey:@"id"] containsObject:myId];
```

"absences" is an NSSet of "Absence" records which is part of my "Employee" record.

Clearly I could loop through "absences" and check each record like this:

```
if let allAbsences = self.employeeRecord.absences {
      for checkAbsence in allAbsences {
           if (checkAbsence.id == myId) {
                existingRecord = true
                break
           }
       }
}
```

but I lose the elegance of the objective-c solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift also has these elegant methods. ;) Just use the same method in swift as you did in objective-c:

```
var existingRecord = self.employeeRecord.absences.valueForKey("id").containsObject(myId)
```

Comment: `AnyObject?` cannot be passed to `contains()`.

Comment: Awesome thanks Christian! I got close to that but couldn't get it to compile - still getting used to the syntax...

Answer (score 0):

with Swift 3 Syntax this would be:

```
(<parent>.<set>?.value(forKey: "<identifier>") as AnyObject).contains(<identifier>)
```